# Make a 2-D array print 'nicer'

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I have the following matrix generated:

```
matrix = [[0] * columns for i in range(rows)]
```

where the user defines the rows and columns in the main sequence.
 Say the user entered the numbers such that `rows = 5` and `columns = 4`. When I print the matrix, I will get the following:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Thats okay, but I would like to make it nicer, so that it would look like this:

```
[
[0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

I believe that you would need to use something like `\n`, but I'm having trouble as to how to implement it. Perhaps theres a built-in function alread that I don't know of? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the [pprint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) module.  It's in the standard library, so you already have it, and it is designed for exactly this type of problem.

Comment: Or, if you can use `numpy`, it does this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
def formattedPrint(matrix):
    print "["
    for i in matrix:
        print(i)
    print "]"
```

Comment: Note the `python-3.x` tag, so your solution will give a syntax error for the OP.

Comment: @SethMMorton I'm not familiar with 3.x. Is this better?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [pprint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) library built into Python. I use it in 2.7, but it is available in Python 3.